# WordPress loop in loop ignore paged

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, dropdown

I have a question about WordPress where I have a loop in a loop but one loop used paged pages. I don't want the other loop to be paged.

This is my loop which doesn't need to get paged:

```
<?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        if(!isset($product_cat[$term->term_id])){
            $product_cat[$term->term_id] = array(
                'name'=>$term->name,
                'slug' => $term->slug,
                'id' => $term->term_id,
                'count' => $term->count,
            );
        }
    }
    endwhile;    
?>
```

I don't know where to start, I can put the result of:

```
global $wp_query;
var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);
```

if is needed.

This is where the result is shown:

```
<section id="woocommerce_product_categories-2" class="widget woocommerce widget_product_categories">
    <select name='product_cat' class='dropdown_product_cat'>
         <option id="" value="">Selecteer een categorie</option>
         <?php
           foreach ($product_cat as $cat) {
         ?>
           <option class="level-0" value="<?php echo $cat['slug'];?>">
             <?php echo $cat['name'].' ('.$cat['count'].')'; ?>
           </option>
         <?php } ?>
    </select>
</section>
```

Can you help me out!